# Does the kernel ever need to access user data?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I'm new to operating systems and was wondering if the kernel ever needs to access user data and if so why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a focused programming question as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

> I'm new to operating systems and was wondering if the kernel ever needs to access user data and if so why?

The primary reason is that the calling conventions used for kernel's system calls are unable to handle an arbitrary amount of data; and to work around the restriction some system calls expect a pointer to the actual data.

For a common example, the system call to open a file might use the address of a file name string (e.g. maybe a "`char * file_name`"), and then the kernel (after carefully validating the address provided by user-space for security reasons) has to read the file name from user-space.